# Is there any way to get an pixel perfect collider generation on pixel sprites?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to add 2D colliders to my pixel sprites, but when I add the collider, it doesn't generate accurately, even with the sprite's outline tolerance at the max [sprite's outline tolerance at the max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn9ce.png). I've also tried using the PixelCollider2D script from https://github.com/RandomiaGaming/Unity2DPixelPerfectCollider, but it doesn't work for me, as it generates a collider from all the sprites on the spritesheet [generates a collider from all the sprites on the spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqw0C.png). Is there any way of being able to generate a pixel-perfect collider for my sprites? Setting them all manually will take far too long. Thank you in advance!